# Can anyone see why these integrals are necessarily equal?

Tags: calculus

Is it possible find a function $u(x)$ so that $[y'(x)+y(x)\tan(x)]^2=(u'(x))^2-(u(x))^2$?

If not, is there an obvious reason why the integrals of the LHS an the RHS respectively over the interval $(0,1)$ are equal?

Comment: Is this of any help? $$u(x) = y(x) \sec(x)\\ u'(x) = y'(x) \sec(x) + y(x) \sec(x) \tan(x)$$
$$\left(u'(x) \right)^2 - (u(x))^2= (y'(x) + y(x) \tan(x))^2 \sec^2(x) - y^2(x) \sec^2(x)$$

Comment: @Marvis: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: but at the moment i am still not entirely sure of how this works. maybe integrating by parts would help?

Comment: I don't understand your second question. The integrals of *what* over that interval are equal?

Comment: @GregMartin: the LHS and the RHS respectively.

Comment: @GregMartin Left hand side of the mentioned equality and right hand side of it!

Comment: If the left and right sides of the equation are equal everywhere on $[0,1]$ and are integrable over $[0,1]$, their integrals are equal.  If the left and right sides are not equal, what is supposed to be the relation between $y$ and $u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a suitable $u$, you might solve the differential equation $u'(x) = \sqrt{(y'(x)+y(x) \tan(x))^2 + u(x)^2}$.  Assuming $y$ and $y'$ are continuous on $[0,1]$, the right side of that differential equation is continuous and locally Lipschitz on $[0,1] \times \mathbb R$, so for any initial condition at some $x_0 \in [0,1]$ we have local existence and uniqueness of solutions.  Moreover, since $\sqrt{A^2 + u^2} \le |A| + |u|$, the solution will exist on all of $[0,1]$.